# Web Audio Clock: getting frequency to sound right

Tags: javascript, audio

Trying in JS to create a single oscillator, with a smooth, non-clicking frequency tone that rapidly turns on and off. Timing for web audio discussed by [Chris Wallace][1]. A timing scheduler can be found by [Aqilah Misuary][2]. This example produces a correct-sounding tone based on the frequency. However, a noticeable click is present. Fixing clicks has been addressed by a posting on [Stack Overflow][3].

First code snippet is based on the Code Pen version (see link 2), changing frequency to 432 Hz.

Second code snippet:
Adapted JS (see links 2 and 3) from these resources, adding ramping, using the 432 Hz frequency,I can get the clicking to stop, but my frequency sound is now blunted, no longer has the correct 432 Hz frequency sound. I suspect that I am doing something wrong, not using the timing or settings correctly. I've tried various timings and settings and even "initial" instead of "exponential" ramping, but none have fixed the issue: clicking gone but frequency sound is now blunted, doesn't retain the correct sound based on the frequency chosen and that would be heard if ramping is not used, leaving the clicking. I must be doing something wrong?

Any way to fix the clicking without blunting the sound?
[1]: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/
[2]: https://codepen.io/aqilahmisuary/pen/ONEKVM
[3]: [Web audio "Click" sound even when using exponentialRampToValueAtTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476178/web-audio-click-sound-even-when-using-exponentialramptovalueattime)

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>
<p><button name="button" id="startBtn">Start</button>
  <button name="button" id="stopBtn">Stop</button></p>
<p>Audio Context Current Time:</p>
<p><span id="clock"></span></p>
<p>nextNotetime:</p>
<p><span id="nextNote"></span></p>

<style>
span, p, button {
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, 'Lucida Sans Typewriter', 'Lucida Typewriter', monospace;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 1000;
    line-height: 26.4px;
    text-align: center;
}

span {
    font-weight: 200;
}
</style>

<script>
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

var audioContext = new AudioContext();
var nextNotetime = audioContext.currentTime;
var clock = document.getElementById("clock");
var nextNote = document.getElementById("nextNote");
var startBtn = document.getElementById("startBtn");
var stopBtn = document.getElementById("stopBtn");
var timerID;

setInterval(function(){ clock.innerHTML = audioContext.currentTime; }, 100);

function playSound(time) {
  
  var osc = audioContext.createOscillator();
  osc.connect(audioContext.destination);
  osc.frequency.value = 432;
  osc.start(time);
  osc.stop(time + 0.1);
  
};

function scheduler() {

    while(nextNotetime < audioContext.currentTime + 0.1) {
        
        nextNotetime += 0.5;
        nextNote.innerHTML = nextNotetime;
        playSound(nextNotetime);
    }

   timerID = window.setTimeout(scheduler, 50.0);
}

startBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

    scheduler();

  }, false);

stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

    clearTimeout(timerID);

  }, false);

if(audioContext.state === 'suspended'){
  audioContext.resume();
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><button name="button" id="startBtn">Start</button>
  <button name="button" id="stopBtn">Stop</button></p>
<p>Audio Context Current Time:</p>
<p><span id="clock"></span></p>
<p>nextNotetime:</p>
<p><span id="nextNote"></span></p>
<style>
span, p, button {
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, 'Lucida Sans Typewriter', 'Lucida Typewriter', monospace;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 1000;
    line-height: 26.4px;
    text-align: center;
}
span {
    font-weight: 200;
}
</style>
<script>
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

var audioContext = new AudioContext();
var nextNotetime = audioContext.currentTime;
var clock = document.getElementById("clock");
var nextNote = document.getElementById("nextNote");
var startBtn = document.getElementById("startBtn");
var stopBtn = document.getElementById("stopBtn");
var timerID;
var gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
var osc;
var rampDuration = 0.3;
gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
setInterval(function(){ clock.innerHTML = audioContext.currentTime; }, 100);
function playSound(time) {  
  osc = audioContext.createOscillator();
  osc.connect(gainNode);
  osc.frequency.value = 432;
  osc.type = "sine";
  gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(1, audioContext.currentTime);
  gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0.0001, audioContext.currentTime + rampDuration);
  gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1, audioContext.currentTime + rampDuration);
  osc.start(time);
  osc.stop(time + 0.01);  
};
function scheduler() {
    while(nextNotetime < audioContext.currentTime + 0.1) {        
        nextNotetime += 0.5;
        nextNote.innerHTML = nextNotetime;
        playSound(nextNotetime);
    }
   timerID = window.setTimeout(scheduler, 50.0);
}
startBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    scheduler();
  }, false);
stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
  }, false);
if(audioContext.state === 'suspended'){
  audioContext.resume();
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that the end goal here is a repeating beep of a given length at a given frequency?

Comment: Maintaining frequency sound (for example correct sound of 432 Hz frequency) is needed. I am not sure about length. The tone I am looking for is a pulsing 432 Hz frequency. So, on and off rapidly without clicking. The number of pulses on and off, ranges from about 4/second to 32/second. Hope that better explains this. Happy to clarify further, as needed.

Comment: 432 Hz is quite specific, and that's fine :-) Can you explain what the final application here will be, so we can come up with the best technique?

Comment: Sure: isochronic tone online-deployed/web generator. These type of tones are a single frequency tone rapidly turned on and off. Need to use web audio clock or other timing mechanism since setTimeout doesn't work with web audio oscillator (see link 1). BTW while 432 Hz is a frequently used isochronic tone, tone frequency can be other values, depending n the sound effect needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, we're essentially dealing with a short repetitive loop that needs *exact* timing, so [an AudioBufferSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode) is our weapon of choice:

> It's especially useful for playing back audio which has particularly stringent timing accuracy requirements, such as for sounds that must match a specific rhythm

Unfortunately that also means we'll need to get our hands dirty and write some DSP code to synthesize that buffer, but it's honestly not that bad (especially since we can just work in floating point numbers, not raw PCM buffers...).

To avoid clicks (where the oscillator is cut off mid-phase, as it were), we take advantage of the facts that a sine wave always starts at zero and we render a single loop of the sound, so all we need to do is make sure the end of the wave does not stop abruptly. We do that by slightly adjusting the length of the tone to make sure the last audible sample is very near to zero.

The example here has a couple of buttons to demonstrate different parameters. You could hook those up into UI components.

```js
var audioContext = new AudioContext();
var gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
var playerNode = null; // Initialized later.

function createLoop(audioContext, toneFrequency, toneDuration, loopDuration) {
  const arrayBuffer = audioContext.createBuffer(
    1,
    audioContext.sampleRate * loopDuration,
    audioContext.sampleRate,
  );
  const channel = arrayBuffer.getChannelData(0); // mono, only deal with single channel
  const toneDurationInSamples = Math.floor(audioContext.sampleRate * toneDuration);
  const phasePerSample = (Math.PI * 2 * toneFrequency) / audioContext.sampleRate;
  let audible = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayBuffer.length; i++) {
    if (audible) {
      let value = Math.sin(phasePerSample * i);
      channel[i] = value;
      // We might slightly overshoot the tone's requested duration
      // but we need to wait for the oscillation to be near zero
      // to avoid an audible click (when the signal "snaps" from an arbitrary
      // value to zero).
      if (i >= toneDurationInSamples && Math.abs(value) < 0.02) {
        audible = false;
      }
    } else {
      channel[i] = 0; // Silence
    }
  }
  return arrayBuffer;
}

function go(hz, length) {
  halt(); // Remove the old player node. We couldn't modify the buffer anyway.
  playerNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
  playerNode.loop = true;
  playerNode.connect(gainNode);

  const buf = createLoop(audioContext, hz, length / 5, length);
  playerNode.buffer = buf;
  playerNode.start();
  audioContext.resume();
}

function halt() {
  if (playerNode) {
    playerNode.stop();
    playerNode.disconnect();
    playerNode = null;
  }
}
function handleVolumeChange(volume) {
  gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(volume, audioContext.currentTime);
}
```

```html
Since an Audio Context can't start with interaction, you'll need to hit a button...

<br />

<button onclick="go(432, 0.5)">Go at 432 hz</button>
<button onclick="go(880, 0.3)">Go faster and at 880 hz</button>
<button onclick="go(1250, 0.1)">Go really fast and high</button>
<button onclick="halt()">Stop going</button>

<br />

Volume: <input type="range" min="0" max="1" value="1" step="0.01" onInput="handleVolumeChange(event.target.valueAsNumber)">
```

Comment: Brilliant!. Thank you. I will also need to add a stop function for when the user needs to stop the tone. I just tried function stop() {playerNode.stop();} with its own button. Stops the tone, but cannot resume using Go. Will experiment to see if I can code a stop function that allows the user to later resume (if needed). Again, thank you!

Comment: @saratogacoach It takes a bit more work, but I just added `halt()` for you – and a demo of a faster loop with a higher pitch too. :)

Comment: I will need to add a volume/gain control (input range slider) so the user can turn the tone volume up or down. Would I try to add the gain for the playerNode? Not sure how to do this, where a "gain" would be placed. Any suggestions, leads appreciated. Thank you again.

Comment: @saratogacoach You were on the right track. Add a gain node and hook the buffer node to it instead of the destination. I edited that into the code :)

Comment: Thank you, again. I am learning a lot about how and where to add gain. Much appreciated!